# ManyToManyField в templates

Tags: form, django

В шаблоне уникальная верстка, необходимо получать названия и значений выделенного элемента ManyToManyField в шаблоне.

**Модель такая:**

```
class UserInterests(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(_("Title"), max_length=255)

class UserData(models.Model):
    interests = models.ManyToManyField(UserInterests, blank=True)
```

При выводе в шаблоне оно отображается полем формы множественного выбора. Но мне так не подходит, нужно чтобы выбирались галочками, делал в forms через виджет:

```
widgets = {"interests":CheckboxSelectMultiple(),}
```

Да, отображается чекбоксами, но со своей версткой, а мне хочется управлять самостоятельно версткой, не просто css подстроить как нужно, а именно свою верстку сделать, что-то вроде:

```
{% for field in form.fields.interests %}
    {{ field.value }}
    {{ field.checked }}
{% endfor %}
```

Как получать доступ к данным названия множественного элемента, и к значению выделения?

Answer (score 2):

Не уверен в Вашем случае, но M2M обычно выводится как model.object.field.all()

```
{% for field in form.fields.interests.all %}
    {{ field.value }}
    {{ field.checked }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Во, во, видимо это не в таком случае. Я так тоже пробовал, но не могу понять почему не выводится весь список значений. Вывожу через фильтр __dict__ {{ form.fields.interests|mypprint }} и получаю {... '_queryset': [<UserInterests: Apple гаджеты>, <UserInterests: handmade>, <UserInterests: авто атрибуты>], ...}, а вот как их вывести на страницу то.